# How do I get the declared functions of a Kotlin class (KClass in M12)?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Basically that. I'm wondering how to get the functions/methods given a KClass... looks like I can only iterate over the properties and extension properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: *You can now get functions of a class with extensions declared in package `kotlin.reflect`: `functions`, `declaredFunctions`, `memberFunctions`, `staticFunctions`, etc.*

Kotlin reflection is a work in progress at the moment. We plan to ship API for introspecting functions in the next milestone, presumably at the end of this summer.

Meanwhile, the only workaround is to use Java reflection for this task.

Comment: Reflection is now more complete.  View the [documentation for Kotlin Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) and specifically that of [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin reflection is more full featured in later milestones include the 1.0 betas.

View the overview documentation for [Kotlin Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) and specifically that of [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html).

For example, given a class you can see member functions using:

```
val functions = Someclass::class.declaredMemberFunctions
```

or properties:

```
val properties = Someclass::class.declaredMemberProperties
```

And to get from a Java Class to a KClass:

```
val kclz = this.javaClass.kotlin
```

See also:  [Kotlin.reflect package API docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/index.html)