# How to acess attributtes and methods of a class in kotlin?

Tags: python, class, kotlin, object, oop

I'm new to kotlin and i am used to python. In python if i run dir(class) i get all names of attributes and methods of that class or object of class.

Is there a way of doing the same in kotlin?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the declared functions of a Kotlin class (KClass in M12)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060995/how-do-i-get-the-declared-functions-of-a-kotlin-class-kclass-in-m12)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? When coding, your IDE should be able to show you all the relevant docs, and they're also available online. Or at runtime, if you don't know whether an object supports a particular method/property, you can use [`is`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators) to check. But that sort of thing isn't often needed in strongly-typed languages like Kotlin, since you usually know what types you're dealing with, and the compiler checks everything for you.

Comment: In strongly typed languages, this is done with reflection. But since it is a strongly typed language, you should rarely ever be doing it.

Comment: Also keep in mind that reflection (depending on build config) won't even be accurate as  your code might undergo minification and unused members will be stripped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `YourClass::class.members` for a list of attributes and `YourClass::class.java.methods` for the methods.